# akka stream: how to reconnect TCP after disconnected

Tags: scala, tcp, akka-stream

I have a simple balancer that dispatch jobs to several external worker processes via TCP:

```
val sinkBalance =
Sink.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
  val balancer = b.add(Balance[ByteString](workerCount))

  for (i <- 0 until workerCount) {

    val codec = Framing.simpleFramingProtocol(500).reversed
    val connection = Tcp(actorSystem).outgoingConnection("127.0.0.1", 3333+i)
    val extConnector = connection.join(codec)

    balancer.out(i) 
      ~> extConnector.async 
        ~> Sink.onComplete(_=>println(s"complete: $i"))
  }

  SinkShape(balancer.in)
})
```

Normally it works great. However, when one of those external worker process get killed, the sub-flow for it will be completed (the *println* statement triggered), but the balancer somehow didn't know that: for the 1st next request, it still distribute jobs to the dead worker, and lead to timeout for that request. From the 2nd next request, thing back to normal, the balancer never use the dead worker again.

So I would like to ask 2 questions:

1. How can I reconnect the broken sub-flow? Maybe automatically, or manually by some event, after restarted the dead worker.
2. How can I modify the code above so that the balancer will no longer use any dead worker?